# Azure Web App, streamlit stuck in `Please wait...`

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, streamlit

I've created a `web app service` with `B1` tier pricing in linux/python3.7

I've hooked up my Azure git to the deployement center, the application builds correctly, I've edited the start command to `python -m streamlit run app.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0`. The app launches, I can access to the URL, but streamlit is stuck into `Please wait...`

[image: Please wait...]

I've tried to enable `WebSockets`, since some people said it was the issue. I could not found the option in the Portal, so I had to use the command `az webapp config set --web-sockets-enabled true --name MyAppName --resource-group MyResourceGroup`. In the output json, I can see the option enabled.

> "webSocketsEnabled": true,

I tried to enable/disable all kind of options in the configuration Portal, but nothing is working. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

(The app works in local mode, and I don't have access to Docker on my local computer, so I can not use this option to build my docker image)

EDIT 1:

In the chrome console, I get an error:

> WebSocket connection to '' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.

But `WebSocket` is enabled, or at least from what my previous commands says

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to reproduce the same error when the webapp is deployed with python 3.9.

*RESULTS:*

[image]

But when I re-deployed a new Web app with Runtime version- Python 3.10 the error was resolved. The below code works fine when the streamlit app runs locally.

```
import  streamlit  as  st

st.set_page_config(page_title="My Test app", page_icon=":tada", layout="wide")

# --- HEADER SECTION ----
st.subheader("Hi, I am test app :wave:")
st.title("A test app to test streamlit")
st.write("I am passionate py developer")
st.write("[Learn More >](https://streamlit.io/)")
```

[image]

Python -m streamlit run app.py
[image]

*RESULTS:*

[image]

Deployed the same to a new app service on azure with Runtime stack Python version 3.10, OS  Linux and SKU B1 Pricing tier (Basic).
*Note- Free tier is not supported for Streamlit app atleast B1 or above is mandatory.*

[image]

Deploy the local code of censusapp in Azure App Service via VS code.

[image]

After the code is deployed > Try accessing the website you will receive an application error, to resolve that. Let’s add  `python -m streamlit run app.py --server.port 8000 --server.address 0.0.0.0>` in the startup command in the Configuration.

[image]

Disable HTTPS Only to OFF and set the configuration settings as below:-
*NOTE: Even if you set this settings to OFF> you can browse your website with https://*

[image]
[image]

After these settings are added and validated, follow the below steps

- Browse your website
- Wait until the website loads
- Now you can see that the error doesn't show up anymore and the website runs successfully in the browser.

[image]

Make sure that if your Web app is running on lower Python version than 3.10 Please re-create a new Web App on Azure with runtime stack python 3.10 to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your time answering this. I will check this in the next days and will give you feedbacks on how it goes for me.